# Why i can not install sharepoint 2013 on a domain controller

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory

It is mentioned that it is not recommended to install SharePoint 2013 on a domain controller. But In my current situation I am setting up my development environment for SP2013; where SharePoint and SQL database and visual studio are on a single VM. so I have installed Active Directory on my windows server 2008 R2 , but does this means that my design for installing SP with AD is not recommended??
Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not recommended that this be done for production deployments, primarily because of security concerns.  If somebody were to compromise some of the admin accounts for SharePoint they could conceivably also take control of your domain and do a lot of harm.

For non-production environments and domains, this is fine and is frequently done (myself included).

Comment: According to [this blog post on MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2014/02/27/setting-up-an-awesome-sharepoint-2013-dev-box-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx), lots of stuff won't work because of "local security groups". What's your take on this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, but possible. Check this video, should be useful for you:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0UVmSSG4dk